# Removing duplicate rows with an expression for the Visibility property

Tags: reporting-services, duplicate-data

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio and I'm trying to stop duplicate rows. The row in question is grouped. Under field properties there is an area called Visibility. For the Hidden value I am entering

```
Fields!fp_id = Previous(Fields!fp_id, True, False)
```

I get the message that it is not a valid Boolean value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide duplicate row SSRS 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738511/hide-duplicate-row-ssrs-2008-r2)

Answer (score 0):

The [`previous` Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255200.aspx) has this signature:

> `Previous(expression, scope)`

Also, you're calling the field itself instead of its `.Value`.

Finally, SSRS usually doesn't like comparison statements in places where it wants a single final value.

Try this:

```
=Iif(Fields!fp_id.Value = Previous(Fields!fp_id.Value), True, False)
```

The `Iif` function has this signature:

> `Iif(TestExpression, TrueValue, FalseValue)`